# Elastic search to include boundary value time stamp

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am trying to include the boundary values in response, but it always rounds up to the nearest end time according to the interval. 
For eg, if I ask data from 10:20 to 10:42 , at 5 mins interval, It will return data for

10:20 - 10:25 - 10:30 - 10:30 - 10:35 - 10:40 but the last 10:40-1:42 is never returned, How can I do this. Here is the query and response.

Query

```
    {
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "range": {
                            "timestamp": {
                                "gte": 1486443000000,
                                "lte": 1486446240000
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "term": {
                            "applicationId": "******"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "term": {
                            "hostId": "*******"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "limit": {
            "value": 0
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "time": {
            "histogram": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "interval": 300000,
                "min_doc_count": 0,
                "extended_bounds": {
                    "min": 1486443000000 ,
                    "max": 1486446240000
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "establishedConnections": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "establishedConnections"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "timestamp": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "took": 8,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
      "total": 21,
      "successful": 21,
      "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "time": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T04:50:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486443000000,
            "doc_count": 50,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 13
            }
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T04:55:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486443300000,
            "doc_count": 50,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 20
            }
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T05:00:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486443600000,
            "doc_count": 50,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 7
            }
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T05:05:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486443900000,
            "doc_count": 50,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 14
            }
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T05:10:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486444200000,
            "doc_count": 50,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 13
            }
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T05:15:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486444500000,
            "doc_count": 50,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 12
            }
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T05:20:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486444800000,
            "doc_count": 50,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 9
            }
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T05:25:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486445100000,
            "doc_count": 50,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 14
            }
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T05:30:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486445400000,
            "doc_count": 50,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 19
            }
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T05:35:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486445700000,
            "doc_count": 50,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 13
            }
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T05:40:00.000Z",
            "key": 1486446000000,
            "doc_count": 40,
            "establishedConnections": {
              "value": 8
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you have this doc with 10:42 value?

Comment: yes I have data for this point, If i will query till 10:45 , it will return the response

Comment: could you show it, i mean the response with returned 10-45 doc, since your current response show nothing in the hits area

Comment: sure , but the above one is from 10:20 to 11:14, so its returning till 11:10, If I change the value of end time to 11:15 then it will include an entry till 11:15 as well

Comment: if i change the end time to be `1486446300000` the response has more more bucket entry as
`{
          "key_as_string": "2017-02-07T05:45:00.000Z",
          "key": 1486446300000,
          "doc_count": 0,
          "establishedConnections": {
            "value": 0
          }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, that in the aggregations part in query, you asked for this:

```
    "aggs": {
        "time": {
            "histogram": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "interval": 300000,
                "min_doc_count": 0,
                "extended_bounds": {
                    "min": 1486443000000 ,
                    "max": 1486446240000
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "establishedConnections": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "establishedConnections"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the `interval` value, you specified **300000** which in milliseconds is exactly **5 minutes**, that's why the last interval from 10:42 is discarded, and all document from this interval are placed under key 10:40.

To make this more formal:

When the aggregation executes, the time field of every document will be evaluated and will be rounded down to its closest bucket. Here is the rounding function that is used:

```
bucket_key = Math.floor((value - offset) / interval) * interval + offset
```

Comment: this I already know, what I need to know is what changes should I make in query to include the left over value

Comment: @MiteshPant, extend the boundary, reduce the interval, it depends on your use case